# How to append ajax data only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append new returned data to my select tag when user selects a drop down menu

```
obj.prototype.getText=function(){
    codes....
    call ajax....

             ajax.callback=function(data){
                   $('#option').append(data);
            }

        }

$('#dropdown').on('change', function(){
    obj.getText()
})
```

My problem is that I only want to append data when the user clicks the dropdown menu the first time.
my code will keep append more same data to my #option as long as user keeps clicking the drop down menu...

Are there anyways to fix this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.one()` instead of `.on()`. It unbinds itself once you trigger the event once:

```
$('#dropdown').one('change', obj.getText);
```

Comment: Hah, here I am recommending a one/once style function but of coure, jQuery has it built in :) +1 For you

Comment: @Bartek: There's nothing wrong with that. There's just one line of code difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply remove the on change event, so it's no longer triggered.

```
$('#dropdown').off('change');
```

I would also look into the notion of a "run once" command. This isn't really what I would recommend here, but going forward, it's a cool thing to know. underscore.js [does it well](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-64)

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) the handler.

something like this.

```
$('#dropdown').on('change', function(){
    obj.getText()
    $('#dropdown').off('change');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

That is probably the best way , turn of event handler , or you could always store a bool value in a hidden field , like

```
       <input type="hidden" id="hidAleadyAppended" />
```

and then set it to true after it is appended once.

This way if you ever need to know if it has been appended already in other code, that is a quick reliable way to check